# Generalized Coxeter's integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left(\frac{a\cos(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Coxeter's integral is a well-known definite integral given by:

$$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+2\cos(x)}\right)dx$$

I am well aware of the 11-page excruciatingly long procedure used to evaluate this integral by Paul Nahin.

This integral made me wonder whether we can find an expression for a generalized integral (similar to that of Coxeter's) of the form:

$$I(a,b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left(\frac{a\cos(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}\right) dx$$

For simplicity, considering the cases for $a=1$, we have:

$$I(b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{1+b\cos(x)}\right) dx$$

I begin simplifying this as Nahin did - using the fact that

$$\arccos x = 2 \arccos \left(\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{2}}\right)$$

We can write the integral as

$$I(b) = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left(\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+(b+1)\cos(x)}{2 + 2b\cos(x)}\right)}\right) dx$$

$$ = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan \sqrt{\left(\frac{1+(b-1)\cos(x)}{1+(b+1)\cos(x)}\right)} dx$$

I have tried two approaches with this integral.

The first approach was the same as followed by Nahin for evaluating Coxeter's integral. It turned out to be a dead end and I could proceed no further with that procedure.

The second approach was to substitute $t = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$ and simplify.

I obtained

$$I(b) = 4 \int_0^1 \arctan \sqrt{\left(\frac{b-(b-2)t^2}{(b+2)-bt^2}\right)} \frac{dt}{t^2+1}$$

Then recalling that

$$\arctan(b) = b \cdot \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+b^2u^2} du$$

I rewrote the original integral into a double integral given by:

$$I(b) = 4 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{(b-(b-2)t^2)((b+2)-bt^2)}}{(t^2+1)\cdot \left[(b+2-bt^2) +(b-(b-2)t^2)\cdot u^2 \right]} dt du$$

I am stuck here. I am not sure, but I have a hunch that we will have to substitute something like

$$bt^2 = (b+2)sin^2v$$

Followed by another trigonometric substitution

$$\tan v = t$$

Can anyone help me simplify this integral further, or suggest a better approach to find $I(b)$, and if possible - $I(a,b)$?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

**Long comment.** As a special case of what I proved quite a long time ago, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1+a\cos x}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{3\pi^2}{16} + \arctan^2\sqrt\frac{a-1}{a+3}-\arctan^2\sqrt{a}. \tag{*} $$

This resolves OP's question in a special case via the identity

$$ I(a, a+1) = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arctan\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{1+(2a+1)\cos x}} \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

which easily follows from $\arccos A = 2 \arctan\sqrt{\frac{1-A}{1+A}}$, just like OP did.

Since I obtained $\text{(*)}$ through a series of non-trivial and painstaking detours, let me not describe the details. (I utilized some identities involving generalized Ahmed integrals that I studied long ago.) I will take time to see if I can find a simpler and/or more general answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint: Take the integral by parts.**
We have that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}arccos(\frac{acos(x)}{1+bcos(x)})dx\\
&=xarccos(\frac{acos(x)}{1+bcos(x)})\bigg|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}xd[arccos(\frac{acos(x)}{1+bcos(x)})]\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}xd[arccos(\frac{acos(x)}{1+bcos(x)})]\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{axsin(x)}{\sqrt{(1+bcos(x))^2-a^2cos^2(x)}}dx\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I don't know how to continue, but I hope it will help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\alpha\arccos\left(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2\cos\theta}\right)\mathrm{~d}\theta$$

Then

\begin{align} I(\alpha)&=\int_0^\alpha\arccos\left(\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2\cos\theta}\right)\mathrm{~d}\theta\\ &=2\int_0^\alpha\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{4\cos\theta}}\mathrm{~d}\theta\\ &=2\int_0^\alpha\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos\sqrt{\frac{3\cos\theta-1}{4\cos\theta}}\right)\mathrm{d}\theta\\ &=\pi\alpha-2\int_0^\alpha\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{3\cos\theta-1}}\mathrm{~d}\theta\\ &=\pi\alpha-2\underbrace{\int_0^\alpha\arctan\left[\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}}\right]\mathrm{d}\theta}_{\theta\to2\theta}\\ &=\pi\alpha-4\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{2}\arctan\left[\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\theta}}\right]\mathrm{d}\theta. \end{align}

Now take into account the parametric integral

$$J(b)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+b^2x^2}\mathrm{~d}x=\frac{1}{b}\arctan b$$

let

$$b=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\theta}}$$

we have

\begin{align} I(\alpha)&=\pi\alpha-4\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{2}\arctan\left[\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\theta}}\right]\mathrm{d}\theta\\ &=\pi\alpha-4\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\theta}}}{1+\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{{1-3\sin^2\theta}}x^2}\mathrm{~d}x\mathrm{d}\theta\\ &=\pi\alpha-4\int_0^1\underbrace{\int_0^\frac{\alpha}{2}\frac{{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-3\sin^2\theta}}}{{1-3\sin^2\theta}+{\cos^2\theta}x^2}\mathrm{~d}\theta}_{\sin\theta\to\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\theta}\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\pi\alpha-{4}{\sqrt{3}}\\ &\quad\cdot\int_0^1\underbrace{\int_0^{\arcsin\left[\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{2x^2+\left(3+x^2\right)\cos^2\theta}\mathrm{~d}\theta}_{\theta\to\arctan \theta}\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\pi\alpha-{4}{\sqrt{3}}\\ &\quad\cdot\int_0^1\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3-3\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-1}}}\frac{1}{\left(1+\theta^2\right)\left(3+3x^2+2\theta^2x^2\right)}\mathrm{~d}\theta\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\pi\alpha-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\\ &\quad\cdot\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3-3\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-1}}}\frac{1}{1+\theta^2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}\theta^2}x\right)^2}\mathrm{~d}x\mathrm{d}\theta\\ &=\pi\alpha-\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{3-3\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-1}}}\frac{\arctan\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}\theta^2}}{\left(1+\theta^2\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{3}\theta^2}}\mathrm{~d}\theta}_{\theta\to\sqrt{3}\theta}\\ &=\pi\alpha-4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{3\cos\alpha-1}}}\frac{\arctan\sqrt{1+2\theta^2}}{\left(1+3\theta^2\right)\sqrt{1+2\theta^2}}\mathrm{~d}\theta. \end{align}